# A short and simple riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics

One day, while playing Minecraft, a player ran at full speed up to a tree and dug into the ground. There, they found a mysterious note. It said:

I am a thing.
If you do something to me, 
and then do the opposite of that thing to me,
You may think you end up with me again, but...
You will end up with the opposite of me.

What is this riddle referring to?

Hint:

> Minecraft has trees made out of cubes.

Comment: It refers to the number zero. If you take the negative of 0, it makes 0, then you take its negative, 0 again, which is also the opposite of 0.

Comment: Hmm... It's certainly possible to think of the number 0 as a thing, but I'd be leaning more towards it being the absence of a thing. I'll clarify if it's generally accepted as too ambiguous.

Comment: At first I wondered "why did someone downvote this"? Then I realized, they were responding to it.

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> $-1$  (or any other negative number)

Explanation:

> Squaring it turns it into 1 and the square root of 1 is 1.
>  So you end up with the opposite of $-1$.

Comment: You're almost there, you've just made a very simple and very common mistake.

Comment: How is "-1" a "thing" ?

Comment: @fffred not all things are tangible things.

Comment: @PaulL Yeah but everything is a thing.

Comment: @paste  ...exactly.

Comment: @Paul, so why would not "zero" be a thing? :(

Comment: The square root of 1 is not 1, it is +/-1. So in terms of the riddle, you end up with both me and the opposite of me.

Comment: @ruudvan The square root of 1 is really 1. Do not mistake that with the solution of $x^2=1$ which has two solutions.

Comment: @ruudvan. Actually the square root of 1 is 1. It's never -1. Never. +/-1 are solutions to the equation $x^2=1$. But it's not the same thing.

Comment: @fffred it is.  Your answer is 100% correct.  It's just not the answer the questioner was hoping for.  That doesn't make it less correct.

Comment: basically, "I am a thing" is a completely null statement.  It has no meaning.  Literally any idea, concept, object, philosophy, or thought is a "thing".  Indeed, one of the [definitions of "thing"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thing?s=t) is: "anything that is or may become an object of thought".

Comment: (likewise, @marius's answer is also correct.  I suspect that Kingrames made the same error that ruudvan made, in believing that the square root of 1 is +/- 1.  There is no "simple and very common mistake" in marius's math, his answer fits the riddle completely.)

Comment: @Marius You are correct that the square root of 1 is always 1, but the *opposite of squaring* (as mentioned in the question) would not be taking the square root, but would rather be finding the positive or negative square root.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain What's a negative sqare root?

Comment: @Marius $x^2 = 1 \therefore x=\pm\sqrt1$.  I meant "(positive or negative) square root" as opposed to "positive square root or negative square root".

Comment: That's interesting. I've always been told, across the board, that when you take the square root, you always write it as both the positive and negative solutions, especially if you're not all the way finished with the problem and you intend to use it elsewhere. Otherwise, you end up with equations that say $5 = -5$ and other such nonsense.

Comment: Wikipedia defines the square root as "In mathematics, a square root of a number $a$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2 = a$" which means that the square root of $25$ is $+/-5$.

Comment: @Marius, fffred, and Paul L, you are all using the principal square root, not the square root. There is a difference between the two terms. You'll note that the riddle doesn't explicitly state that you'll only find one root (although it is tricky about it!) or that the root will be a square or cubic root. For all you know it might be $x^6$, $x^8$, or $x^4$. The riddle was ultimately only asking for an even number of roots. I could give the checkmark, but I can't in good conscience do that for an answer that is explicitly stating something that is wrong.

Comment: @Kingrames http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRoot.html "In common usage, unless otherwise specified, "the" square root is generally taken to mean the principal square root." You asked for "the" opposite, not an opposite.  By every normal interpretation of the riddle's wording, this answer is correct.

Comment: @PaulL I didn't say you'd ONLY end up with the opposite. I just said you'd end up with the opposite. You could also end up with something else. And you do.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer is: If you

> rotate a cube around one horizontal axis, then around the other horizontal axis, then perform the same two rotations in the opposite order, the cube ends up upside-down.

This doesn't work very well as the "opposite" actions aren't proper opposites.

Comment: That's pretty cool, though. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 0):

An answer related to Minecraft

> Well it might be wood blocks in Minecraft, We make planks out of wood and then when we try to make wood out of planks, we fail.